# Mysterious line in my Vase-print

Tags: creality-cr-10

Besides the ugly filament hairs (dealing with those separately), I've got this weird horizontal line in my print that's hard to miss. It's perfectly straight, and I can't figure out what's causing it. I'm using the Spiralize Outer Contour setting.

At first, I thought maybe the wall was getting thinner for a couple of layers, but nope. It seems like the nozzle is pulling to the inside direction for a bit for a few layers, because there's also a line on the inside of the vase. On the inside, the line is kind of sticking out. But I have no idea why. I'm not seeing this on my Cura preview, it really happens during the print.

Setup:

- Printer: Creality 3D CR-10S Pro V2
- Extruder: Bondtech DDX v3 Direct Drive
- Hotend: Slice Engineering Mosquito Magnum

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it happen reproducibly in the same location for multiple attempts? If not, it looks like you just had a momentary problem with extrusion.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you got the filament hairs and blobs on a vase-mode print.  Those artifacts make me wonder if something else is going on with the print in general.  Is it correctly spiralizing?  that is, the nozzle should move in one continuous line around the perimeter without moving away at any point.  

Secondarily:  on the far side of the vase, is it pushed out, instead of in, or has the print contracted entirely - that whole band is pulled in uniformly around the perimeter of the print for those layers?